# Validating invalid query parameters using raml

Tags: raml

I just wanted to know, is there any good way to handle invalid query parameters which is not mentioned in the raml file. So one way to do is using required but problem is the fields in my use case can be optional. So is there a better way to check the query is invalid and return like a 400 bad request response to the user? Any help would be appreciated.

```
So currently I have this:
/products:
  securedBy: [oauth_2_0]
  displayName: products
  type:
    readOnlyCollection:
      exampleCollection: !include test.json
  get:
    queryParameters:
      catalog:
        displayName: catalog
        type: string
        required: false
```

The problem is suppose when a user passes like an invalid query parameter, I should be able to return user that it is invalid and return like a 400.How can I do that.

Thanks
Joel

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried already, so we can improve on it and show you what to change.

Comment: @Adam, I have updated the question with what I have so far.